# Android Studio cannot be initialized (0xc0000005)

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

I have just installed Android Studio in my new notebook running Windows 10 -  64 bits with Java SE 8 152, but it suddently it stopped working, like, every time I try to run the Android Studio, the error message below appears:

> "The application cannot be initialized correctly (0xc0000005)"

I've already tried to reinstall, run as admin, deactivate the antivirus... nothing worked.

Comment: did you try this? http://www.eassos.com/how-to/fix-error-code-0xc0000005.php

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had similar problem and disabling "Force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR)" for studio64.exe in Windows Defender Security Center > App & browser control > Exploit protection > "Program settings" tab fixed this (you have to point to exact binary file with full path as using just executable name doesn't seem to work).

Comment: You can do the same with this command from an elevated powershell: `Set-ProcessMitigation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe' -Disable ForceRelocateImagess`

Answer (score 6):

AVD Settings -> Edit Image set Graphics to Software GLES 2.0

[image]

Comment: What is AVD settings and how to I open it?

Comment: @MomenZaqout thanks, but it is still not clear how to open it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and disabling **Data Execution Prevention** for studio64.exe in `Windows Defender Security Center > App & browser control > Exploit protection > Program settings` tab fixed this (you have to point to exact binary file with full path).

My *Force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR)* was already disabled by default

Answer (score 1):

Both configure Windows Defender.

Open "Windows Defender Security Center" from Windows settings.
Open "App and browser control". Open "Exploit Protection Settings" in "Exploit Protection".Select "Program Settings" at the top, then select in the following order:

"Add and customize programs" "+" button

"Add by program name"

Enter "studio64.exe" and set the following:

"Force image randomization (mandatory ASLR)"

Check "Override system settings"
turn off _

"Randomize virtual memory allocation (bottom-up ASLR)"

Check "Override system settings"
turn off _

Answer (score 0):

At my case, happened at Vs2019 enterprise and pro, and VS 2022

After reading and searching at internet, the error caused by one kind of computer virus..

After I re-install windows, and re-install all application freshly downloaded from internet (not .exe from local hardisk), the error gone.

.exe files can be infected by some viruses, so I need to re-download fresh .exe from internet (guine source from producer)

Answer (score -1):

Install fresh Windows and don't install Java kit (JDK) this caused the 0xc000005 problem for me.