# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application

Tags: android-studio

I just installed many times Android.Studio.3.4.1.0.x64 but when I want to open it, I get this error what 
**The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio cannot be initialized (0xc0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500401/android-studio-cannot-be-initialized-0xc0000005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabling "Force randomization for images (Mandatory ASLR)" for studio64.exe in Windows Defender Security Center > App & browser control > Exploit protection > "Program settings" tab fixes this sometimes

Answer (score 1):

If this was a snap install, just install the standalone version instead. Otherwise, most likely you are missing certain 32-bit libraries, or when it is Windows, respectively DLL (this is what the error code tries to tell).